# Server(10.0.0.1) replying for client (10.0.0.2)request but it's not reaching to client

Tags: server, client

Client(10.0.0.2) requesting for  TFTP packets to server(10.0.0.1)

Server receiving client request and server replying to client, But it's not reaching to client

For more information about client server communication

12:09:44.319861 IP 10.0.0.2.1664  10.0.0.1.69: TFTP, length 42, RRQ "system.bit" octet timeout 5    blksize  1468

12:09:44.322153 IP 10.0.0.1.60883  10.0.0.2.1664: UDP, length 25

12:09:44.326362 IP 10.0.0.1.48456  10.0.0.2.1664: UDP, length 25

12:09:44.326391 IP 10.0.0.1.41699  10.0.0.2.1664: UDP, length 25

12:09:44.346308 IP 10.0.0.1.52417  10.0.0.2.1664: UDP, length 25

12:09:44.346326 IP 10.0.0.1.49426  10.0.0.2.1664: UDP, length 25

12:09:44.376349 IP 10.0.0.1.53490  10.0.0.2.1664: UDP, length 25

But After doing ifconfig eth0 down and ifconfig eth0 up on server side The communication is proper
After making above steps it's looks below

12:15:32.320374 IP 10.0.0.2.1664  10.0.0.1.50861: UDP, length 4

12:15:32.320436 IP 10.0.0.1.50861  10.0.0.2.1664: UDP, length 1472

12:15:32.320497 IP 10.0.0.2.1664  10.0.0.1.50861: UDP, length 4

12:15:32.320562 IP 10.0.0.1.50861  10.0.0.2.1664: UDP, length 1472

12:15:32.320622 IP 10.0.0.2.1664  10.0.0.1.50861: UDP, length 4

What might be the reason for why server reply not reaching to client, and how to debug it.
I want to where packet gets dropped in server side.

Please reply if anybody knows the answer....Thanks

I tried to get TFTP packets from server

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Using Yacto build  (OpenBmc), I am downloading tftp boot.bin from linux machine to my board,
Some times not able to download boot.bin file from linux machine,

After doing ifconfig down and up in My linux machine then i am able to download the file properly in board ,
In server i am using ftgmac100.c ethernet driver 

There is no any issue with board,  Because What ever board sending tftp request received by Linux machine(Server) , Server also replying but it's not reaching to board, Some where it's dropping, I hope it's dropping at some layer in Server.
Both are connected directly